# How to properly modify attached hibernate collections without too many side effects

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, java-stream

I have the following code:

I have a unidirectional one-to-many relationship between Article and Comments:

```
@Entity
public class Article {

       @OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true)
       @JoinColumn(name = "article_id")
       private List<Comment> comments= new ArrayList<>();
        …
 }
```

I used set `ophanRemoval=true` in order to mark the "child" entity to be removed when it's no longer referenced from the "parent" entity, e.g. when you remove the child entity from the corresponding collection of the parent entity.

Here is an example:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

public Article modifyComment(Long articleId) {

    Article article = repository.findById(articleId);

    List<Comments> comments = article.getComments();

    //Calls a method which modifies removes some comments from the collection based on some logic
    removeSomeComments(comments); //side effect

    modifyComments(comments); //side effect
    .....

    return repository.save(article);
    }
}
```

So I have some statements that perform some actions on the collection, which will then get persisted in the database. In the example above I am getting the article from the database, performing some mutations on the object, by deleting/modifying some comments and then saving it in the database.

I am not sure what's the cleanest way of modifying collections of objects without having to many side-effects, which leads to an error-prone code (my code is more complex and requires multiple mutations on the collection).

Since I am inside the transaction any changes (adding, deleting or modifying children) to the collection will be persisted the next time `EntityManager.commit()` is called.

However, I tried to refactor this code and write it in more expressive functional style:

```
public Article modifyComment(Long articleId) {

    Article article = repository.findById(articleId);

    List<Comment> updatedComments = article.getComments().stream()
             filter(some logic..) //remove some comments from the list based on a filter
             sorted()
            .filter(again some logic) //do more stuff
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    article.add(updatedComments);

    return repository.save(article);
}
```

I like this approach more, as it short, concise and more expressive. 
However this won't work since it throws: 
`A collection with cascade=“all-delete-orphan” was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance`

That's because I am assigning a new list (`updatedComments`) .
If I want to remove or modify children from the parent I have to modify the contents of the list instead of assigning a new list.

So I had to do this at the end:

```
article.getComments().clear();
article.getComments().addAll(updatedComments);
repository.save(article)
```

Do you consider the second example a good practice?

I am not sure how to work with collections in JPA. 
My business logic is more complex and i want to avoid having 3-4 methods that mutate a given collection (attached to a hibernate session) which was passed in as parameter.

I think the second example has less potential for side effects because it doesn't mutate any input parameter. What do you think?

(I am using Spring-Boot 2.2.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually try and turn the predicate logic used in your filter

```
.filter(some logic..) //remove some comments from the list based on a filter
```

to be used within `removeIf` and perform the modification as:

```
Article article = repository.findById(articleId);
article.getComments().removeIf(...inverse of some logic...) //this
return repository.save(article);
```

Comment: In general, I was looking more for answers/ideas how one can tackle such methods with many side-effects (My logic is a bit more complex than the example shown above, so it still requires iterating with streams which create new detached collections from the hibernate session)

But in this particular case, your solution is acceptable for this piece of code, as it avoids the three lines at the end, which updates the existing entity with the new list. Therefore I am going to mark it as accepted for now, unless there any other better solutions/approaches.

Comment: @YetAnotherUser Sure, I can understand my answer not relating much to the underlying problem that you might be facing with the hibernate session. Just that, it might be worth highlighting it in another question emphasizing specifically on the detached collections aspect and looking forward to an answer in that direction. My suggestion was more towards updating a referenced collection without collecting information in another and then proceeding further.